# Use AJAX to validate a web address

Tags: javascript, ajax, validation, url

Below is the explanation of my question.

**Case:**

I am just thinking it aloud here so please correct me if I am on the wrong path.
I am working on this B2B system. I am building a "configurator" application for the client so that he can customize the page as he wants. There is a form which expects the user to add 2 urls.

**Problem:**

I now want to validate these urls. Currently I am using a regex pattern in js to validate the url pattern. But somehow I want to confirm that although the urls have the right pattern, they are not broken.

**Possible Solution:**

What I was thinking to make an ajax call or hit the urls using js and see that I do not get any error code in the header (such as 404).

So is it possible or I am just being stupid? If possible what would be the best way to go around it.

Thanks
Jehanzeb

Comment: As @Quentin explained, such a validation client-side won't be reliable enough. That said, you could use a server-side validation. What server-side technology are you using?

Comment: It's a bad idea to query random URLs.

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't really see the bad in that, as their output isn't used. Maybe they could be used to DDOS, but that would really be an original vector of attack.

Comment: @ClementHerreman if you relay the DDOS / any other attack through your server, you could be called for responsibility.

Comment: @JanDvorak I agree, but with some CSRF token on the AJAX form, and authentication needed to use the AJAX API, that would probably slow down 99.99% of potential attackers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) would prevent you seeing the status code on most sites.

The only way to test them would be to resolve them from a server. You could, however, write a web service that does that and hit it with Ajax. (Make sure you cache results, and don't allow too many requests to the same server in a given time period to avoid being used to launch attacks).

Comment: What about a server-side URL validation as he wants, called by the client-side?

Comment: @sp00m it would be possible to use a server as a relay. You can suggest that as an answer.

Comment: I think that would do the trick. Quentin's answer seems to be the best approach to get to it. And thanks for the last comment "(Make sure you cache results, and don't allow too many requests to the same server in a given time period to avoid being used to launch attacks)". I did not think of that (although it would be really necessary here). Thanks.